# Spring angular multipart missing

Tags: spring, angular

i'm tryning to send a formdata containine an id and a file from angular to spring, file is well uploaded but the id is not. I'm getting the error:
Error 400: Required request part 'ao_id' is not present.

my service:

```
 addResult(input: FormData): Observable<number> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log("id = " + input.get("ao_id"));// prints correctly the vaue of ao_id
    return this.http
      .post(this.resultUrl, input, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

my rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="addResult", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"multipart/form-data"} )

    public ResponseEntity<Void> addResult(@RequestPart("resultat") MultipartFile file,
                                        @RequestPart("ao_id") int ao_id
                                        ){
        ...

    }
```

Comment: Try to check the request send from Angular to Spring controller. Then you will know for sure is this Angular or Spring question

Answer (score 0):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/gtaows/services/aoRes/addResult
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
$wsep:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
connection:Close
content-language:fr-FR
content-type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
date:Mon, 15 Jan 2018 14:40:49 GMT
server:WebSphere Application Server/8.0
transfer-encoding:chunked
x-powered-by:Servlet/3.0
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:597786
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPjCoDBx5K0jTLx2v
Host:localhost:4200
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/ao/list/result/27
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryPjCoDBx5K0jTLx2v
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resultat"; filename="avis (1).xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryPjCoDBx5K0jTLx2v
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ao_id"

27
------WebKitFormBoundaryPjCoDBx5K0jTLx2v--
Name
appelOffres
/gtaows/services/aoRes
info?t=1516027177172
/sockjs-node
addResult
/gtaows/services/aoRes
```